# Removing NSStatusItem view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, nsstatusitem

One I set a view for NSStatusItem by setView:, how can i remove it later on if I want to? Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting it to `nil`?

Answer (score 9):

To remove it, just call:

```
[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] removeStatusItem: myStatusItem]
```

This works even when you define your status item through setTitle or setImage.